# Getting info from multiple maps in c++ and comparing

Tags: c++, c++11, maps

I'm trying to do something a bit weird with a bunch of maps in c++. (If I call them dictionaries, I apologize. Used to working in Python 2.7.)

I have fifty maps, each one representing the top five growing cities in a state. The key is the city name, the mapped value its rate of growth. (EX.Alaska: {anchorage: 112.55; boonies: 106.22;...} The five fastest growing cities in each state.) What I want to do is compare all of these mapped values, find the five with the highest, and print out the name of the city they belong to.

In addition to that fact I'm comparing 250 numbers to start with, I don't know the mapped values or keys until the program runs. It's taking this data from a massive txt file of over 19,000 lines, finding the five highest per state, and then creating a dictionary for each state.

I have no idea on how to access all of these values without knowing what their keys are, or even how to compare all of these numbers at once. I need more help with the former than the latter, but anything will be helpful.

EDIT:

Attempting to answer all the questions asked:

How I got the fifty maps is from a custom class I wrote. The txt file with the data is too large to be read all at once, so I wrote a class that will take read a certain section of the file, find the names and values of the top five in the section, and return it as a map with five pairs: the name of the city and its value. With each state being a section, it will return fifty maps, which each contain five pairs. So map Alaska will have {city: growth value; city2: growth value2...} Then there will be map Arizona, map Alabama, etc. At the moment, I'm calling the function 50 different times with different sections to read. Each time I call the function, it returns the map of the top five pairs. I hope that's clearer.

I need the data as a map because I need the name to print out at the end, in addition to the growth value to compare and find the best. However, now that I'm thinking about it more, I'm considering adding a function in the class that keeps a vector of all the city names and one of just the growth values. I could take the rate vector and compare, then find its corresponding name in the other vector with some kind of counter variable. Not sure if that would work any better or any easier, but a possibility that comes to mind.

Comment: Why would you need to know their keys if each city's map only has five elements to begin with? (at least that was how I read your decryption). And a [`std::map<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) iterator iterates over the `std::pair<>`s in the map, holding the key in `first` and the value in `second`.

Comment: An interesting question that comes to mind is why do you store the intermediate results in a `map` indexed by the name of the city... You could store them in vectors, or in a `map` indexed by growth... Is that a hard requirement? I mean, it is not too complicated to work with what you have, but it might be simpler otherwise. For example, while computing those maps you could also track the best five overall...(do you even need to track the 5 per state?) Also, it might be helpful to know how you have the data stored. Is that a `vector<map<string,double>>`?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas the OP says "I have fifty maps", thus he doesn't have a `vector` of `map`s. Also the author states "print out the name of the city", so he can't store the information in a simple `vector`. Unless he stores it in two vectors, which is kinda pointless when he can use a `map`...

Comment: @PawełStawarz: *I have 50 maps*, **how**? that does not say whether he keeps 50 variables, a vector of maps or a `map<string,map<string,double>>` with the outer map value being the state. The question stands. Regarding the other comment, you can keep as complex a data structure as you want inside of a vector. In fact, I would have created a type to hold the city, state and growth and then operate on that, most probably with vectors.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas "50 maps" means "50 variables of type `map`" AFAIK. But let's wait for the author to clarify. The quote "EX.Alaska: {anchorage: 112.55; boonies: 106.22;..." would suggest my version tho - it hints there's a map called "Alaska".